# Coefficient of generating function involving Fibonacci numbers

Tags: generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

Given the generating function
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n = \prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1-x^{F_{i+2}-1}}
$$
where $F_i$ is the $i$th Fibonacci number, how can I find what $a_n$ is?

Partial fraction decomposition seems like a possibility, but it is really messy.

Do I have to rely on asymptotics only? What can I do then?

Comment: Any empirical data on the $a_n$?

Comment: @lhf I expect that if I divide this coefficient by $\binom{N-1}{n-1}$ and take the limit as $N\to\infty$, I should get $n!\prod_{j=2}^n (F_{j+2}-1)^{-1}
$.
That is why precise asymptotics might suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You could Taylor expand the rhs but this will never end but you can get the $a_n$'s. DOing it, you would generate the sequence
$$\{1,1,2,2,4,4,6,7,10,11,14,16,21,23,29,32,40,43,52,57,69,75,88,96,113,122,141,153,
   \cdots\}$$ which is $A136343$ in $OEIS$

In the links section, you will see that Alois P. Heinz provided a table of the $a_n$'s ) for $0 \leq n \leq 3500$.

Unfortunately, the $OEIS$ page does not provide much information and nothing about the asymptotics.

Comment: Do you know what the given formula for a(n),
a(n) = [x^(2n) y^n] 1/Product_{j>=2} (1-y*x^A000045(j)),
means? What does [x^(2n) y^n] stand for?